# Removing has_key from HTMLTestRunner

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am using HTMLTestRunner to create an HTML report for my unit test. I suppose the code for HTMLTestRunner provided [here](http://tungwaiyip.info/software/HTMLTestRunner.html) is written and optimized for python 2 and before, because I got three errors regarding incompatibility with python 3 like use of **StringIO instead of io**.

Now, line 639 has a `has_key` method defined, in this code snippet

```
def sortResult(self, result_list):
    # unittest does not seems to run in any particular order.
    # Here at least we want to group them together by class.
    rmap = {}
    classes = []
    for n,t,o,e in result_list:
        cls = t.__class__
        if not rmap.has_key(cls):
            rmap[cls] = []
            classes.append(cls)
        rmap[cls].append((n,t,o,e))
    r = [(cls, rmap[cls]) for cls in classes]
    return r
```

Since python 3 has `has_key` removed from [python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins), so I get error regarding this. Since I am not that much familiar with python, I searched and found that `in` can be a suitable replacement. So how can I replace this `has_ key` method? I tried by simply replacing `has key` with `in` but it failed and got an invalid syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
if not rmap.has_key(cls):
```

try

```
if cls not in rmap:
```

You can see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.1/reference/expressions.html#in) for details.